# Возможно ли обособление "на протяжении всей своей трудовой деятельности"?

Tags: пунктуация

Возможно ли обособление: "Александр работал водителем. Этот человек(,) на протяжении всей своей трудовой деятельности(,) был настолько погружен в рутину будней, что не заметил хода времени".
Каким правилом это регулируется? Если невозможно, то почему? Объясните, пожалуйста! Спасибо заранее!

Answer (score 1):

*Этот человек **на протяжении всей своей трудовой деятельности** был настолько погружен в рутину будней, что не заметил хода времени.*

Обстоятельственный оборот не обособляется, он входит в сотав основного сообщения и уточняющим или имеющим дополнительное значение не является.